# SwiftUI @StateObject couldn't refresh view

Tags: xcode, swiftui, observedobject

I can't see the change in the Text object on the ContentView page. However, when I run the same code in .onReceive with print, I can see the change. What's the problem here?

I wanted to manage the state of the game from a different place and the operation of the game from a different place. Is the logic I made wrong?

**Enum**

```
enum GameSituation {
    case play
}
```

**Game Config**

```
class GameConfig: ObservableObject {
    @Published var randomCellValue: Int = 0
    @Published var timer = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    func startGame() {
        determineRandomCell()
    }
    
    func determineRandomCell() {
        randomCellValue = Int.random(in: 0...11)
    }

    func playSound(soundfile: String, ofType: String) {
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundfile, ofType: ofType){
            do{
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Game Situation**

```
class GameSituations: ObservableObject {
    @Published var gameConfig = GameConfig()
    
    func gameSituation(gameSituation: GameSituation) {
        switch gameSituation {
        case .play:
            gameConfig.startGame()
        }
    }
}
```

**Content View**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var gameSituation = GameSituations()
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(gameSituation.gameConfig.randomCellValue)")
            .padding()
            .onReceive(gameSituation.gameConfig.timer, perform: { _ in
                gameSituation.gameSituation(gameSituation: .play)
                print("random: \(gameSituation.gameConfig.randomCellValue)")
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had multi issue I solved all, your first and big issue was, that you are initializing an instance of an **ObservableObject** but using another one! second one was that you forgot using StateObject of **GameConfig** in your View, as you can see in your code, you did used StateObject of **GameSituations** but not **GameConfig**, if you ask why, because it is **Publisher**!

*My best recommendation: try just use one **ObservableObject**! using 2 deferent **ObservableObject** that has binding with together has such a issue that you can see! try organise all your code to one **ObservableObject**.*

---

```
enum GameSituation {
    case play
}
```

---

```
class GameConfig: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: GameConfig = GameConfig()    // <<: Here

    @Published var randomCellValue: Int = 0
    @Published var timer = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    func startGame() {
        determineRandomCell()
    }
    
    func determineRandomCell() {
        randomCellValue = Int.random(in: 0...11)
    }

    func playSound(soundfile: String, ofType: String) {
        
        print(soundfile)


    }
}
```

---

```
class GameSituations: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: GameSituations = GameSituations()  // <<: Here

    let gameConfig = GameConfig.shared        // <<: Here
     
    func gameSituation(gameSituation: GameSituation) {
        switch gameSituation {
        case .play:
            gameConfig.startGame()
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var gameSituation = GameSituations.shared     // <<: Here
    @StateObject var gameConfig = GameConfig.shared            // <<: Here
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(gameConfig.randomCellValue.description)          // <<: Here
            .onReceive(gameConfig.timer, perform: { _ in      // <<: Here

                       gameSituation.gameSituation(gameSituation: .play) 
                        print("random: \(gameSituation.gameConfig.randomCellValue)")
        
                    })

    }
}
```